# Hilbert symbol over 2-adic field

Tags: local-fields, hilbert-symbol

Let $F$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_2$, and let $(-,-)_F$ be the quadratic Hilbert symbol over $F$. Is the following true?

$(-1,-1)_F=1$ if and only if $\sqrt{-1}\in F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For example, $(-1,-1)_F = 1$ for *all* quadratic extensions $F/\mathbf Q_2$.  This was discussed a few days ago on math.stackexchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965273/over-which-extensions-of-mathbb-q-2-is-x2y2z2-isotropic).